# Linux using wrong python version

Tags: python, linux

I have a Linux drive with no root access. It has Python 2.4.2 installed in `/usr/bin/python` directory.

```sh
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I installed Python 2.7.8 in my local folder:

```sh
cd /usr2/steve/bin
ls
python2.7
```

If I still run Python it starts older version:

```sh
python
Python 2.4.2 (#1, May  6 2011, 13:26:21) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I have added `/usr2/steve/bin` to the `PATH`:

```sh
echo $PATH
/usr2/steve/usr2/steve/bin:/usr2/steve/local/mnt/workspace/steve/Python-2.7.8:/usr2/steve/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/gnome/bin:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin
```

How do I force the system to use the newer Python version as opposed to the older one?

Comment: I highly doubt that's your actual `$PATH`; it should have at least `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` as well. Not to mention that most shells use `$` or `#`, not `>`. Most likely, you got the order of your real PATH wrong. Please show the actual contents.

Comment: are you sure changing the system python won't screw your OS? You can use the new python by simply using the full path or export the path in your .bashrc .

Comment: Added the actual path output. I was trying to avoid unnecessary information.

Comment: also check your .bash_profile or .bashrc or etc for an alias for python command.

Comment: Do you have access to pip? Aka: `pip install virtualenv` ?

Answer (score 0):

You only have a `python2.7` binary in your `/usr2/steve/bin` folder. You can make a symlink, then just calling `python` should work:

```
cd /usr2/steve/bin
ln -s python2.7 python
```

Comment: With this now on I get correct path on doing which python.
>which python
/usr2/steve/bin/python

But when I run python, it still is running the old one.

Comment: This really shouldn't happen. You can type `alias` in your shell, maybe there is an alias defined for `python`, `which` wouldn't know about that. Otherwise you can try logging out and back in to see if the problem persists.

Comment: If you add the symlink, you'll also need to invoke `hash -r`.  Your shell will search your PATH for a program the first time you call it, and it remembers that location.  If you call `python` once and the shell finds it in /usr/bin, and then you add the symlink in `/usr2/steve/bin`, the shell will continue to invoke python from `/usr/bin` until you force it to do another PATH search.

Answer (score 0):

make your life simple by creating an alias. Are you using BASH (hopefully you are)? If so this is the syntax

```
alias pythonsteve='/usr2/steve/bin/python2.7'
```

(drop the `=` sign if you are running CSH). Next, run to verify

```
$pythonsteve -c 'import sys; print sys.prefix'
/usr2/steve/bin
```

Put the alias command in your shell user start-up file. On typical BASH installs this is the file `~/.bashrc`. Note, when you manually edit the `~/.bashrc` file you must either log out/log in, or run `source ~/.bashrc` for the commands to execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python 2.7 you can specify it by appending it after 'python'

> which python2.7

Comment: This won't run python2.7 - `which` just tells you where the python2.7 binary is.

Comment: yes, i know but if you want to use python2.7, you have to specify it like so. the code is an example. If you want to run it you just need to type 'python2.7.